# Insertar datos en un array dentro de un objecto

Tags: php

Cuando intento insertar valores a un array que esta dentro de un objecto me imprime el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Alumno as array

Estoy intentando introducir números aleatorios en el campo `nota` con el siguiente código :

```
public $alumnos = array();

public function asignarNotas() {

    foreach($this->alumnos as &$value){
        $value['nota'][] = random_int(5, 10);
    }
}
```

La estructura de los datos es la siguiente :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Alumno)#3 (4) {
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(5) "Alumno1"
    ["apellido"]=>
    string(7) "Apellido1"
    ["dni"]=>
    string(9) "1A"
    ["nota"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que acceder al campo `nota` de la siguiente forma:

`$value->nota[] = random_int(5, 10);`

El problema es que tu variable es un objeto, no puedes hacer uso de los corchetes para acceder a un campo ya que como dice el error, debes de tratar al objeto como tal y usar el operador `->`.

Comment: Es correcto. Y además no tiene que pasar `$value` por referencia usando `&`, como hace ahora, sino que puede escribirlo así simplemente: `foreach($this->alumnos as $value){` ...